# php regex finding double brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have some text that is submitted, and it will contain words in double brackets, but there can be some only in single brackets. But I only want the ones in double brackets.

Example:

> [[test]] [test1] [[test2]] [test5] [[test3]]

With other words etc in the same string...

So for instance:

> [[test]] the quick [test1] brown [[test2]] fox [[test3]] jumped [mytest] over the lazy [[test4]] dog

Right now I have a preg_match_all with:

```
(preg_match_all('/\\[.*?\\]\\]/is',$str,$match))
```

But, it also pulls the single bracket ones... and I suck at regex.

Does anyone have any input on how I can pull just the double bracket ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead.

```
\[{2}.*?\]{2}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bW0mM6/1

The `{2}` requires 2 occurrences. You are only checking for one bracket with your expression.

PHP Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f16f7e102d822e31dc128a384f8090181c7461d

PHP Usage:

```
$str = '[[test]] [test1] [[test2]] [test5] [[test3]]';
preg_match_all('/\[{2}(.*?)\]{2}/is',$str,$match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
)
```

Also note I captured the double bracketed values in the PHP demo, not sure if that is what you wanted.